# Possible to pass data from a ViewController to a Child of another View controller when seguing to the parent of the child?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass some data from a View Controller to a Child of another ViewController(parent) when i segue to the ParentVC

i tried this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@",segue.identifier);

    ChildVC *transfer = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test"]) {
        transfer.testLabel = @"Pass this data";
    }
}
```

but its not passing the data over to the child when i segue over to the Parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the id of segue.destinationViewController to your class ChildVC

Try replacing `ChildVC *transfer = segue.destinationViewController;` with the following:

`ChildVC *transfer = (ChildVC *) segue.destinationViewController;`

Comment: so i set this from a previous VC in prepare to segue, not in the Parent VC?

Comment: Yes, if you are going from child VC to parent VC

Comment: its not passing over to the Child

Comment: So  if you are going from Parent VC to Child VC then the code needs to be Parent VC

Comment: sorry if you misunderstood. im going from a Previous VC to the Parent, which i have a container view with the ChildVC, need to send data to ChildVC from the Previous VC

Comment: So check that you can pass data from the Previous VC to the Parent VC, if you can then either pass it to the Child VC if you have a reference to it, or store it in the Parent VC and pass it in on the prepareForSegue method

Comment: why would i send it through prepareForSegue to the child? Its a container view it shows up byitself. I thought i only send data from Previous VC to the Parent with PrepareForSegue

Comment: Its a good thought to cast to the right VC type (Without it, OP must be seeing a compiler warning).  But casting won't change run time behavior.  This, sadly, is definitely not a correct answer.  The problem must lie in the definition and handling of the `testLabel` property on the destination vc.

Comment: @danh so what is the solution to passing data from a previous vc to a child vc in a container view of a segued Parent vc?

Comment: As I indicated, the problem lies elsewhere.  Need to change the question to explain the destination vc and its properties (and, if its germane, its child vcs).

Comment: Makes better sense to update the original question.

Comment: @danh i dont understand

Comment: Your question does not reflect the issue you are trying to solve. You have failed to fully explain how your view controllers are setup. It is impossible to solve your problem by answering your question - hence @danh comment to update the question.

Comment: this is how my VCs are set up, http://imgur.com/kPvTcCS 
i want to pass data from the first vc you see on the left to the grey child vc